# Unserialize return false

Tags: serialization

How come the unserialize function return false for:

a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:\"type\";s:6:\"isisbn\";s:2:\"id\";s:2:\"85\";}}

Code:

```
        if (unserialize($stringTempList)) {
            return unserialize($stringTempList);
        }else{
            $this->messageBad[] = 'unserialize failed';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by running stripslashes()

Code:

```
    if (unserialize(stripslashes($stringTempList))) {
        return unserialize(stripslashes($stringTempList));
    }else{
        $this->messageBad[] = 'unserialize failed';
    }
```